# How Can i Change App ICon,Splashscreen in worklight Hybrid App

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

How Can i Change App Icon,Splash screen in work-light Hybrid App
and also i need to show Loading/Processing images when inserting/updating record into Database or any time delay for operation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stack Overflow is meant for programming questions. You should first try to implement what you want, and if you then fail or have additional technical questions, open a question.

Before you begin implementing your application, learn the product first.
IBM provides both Getting Started tutorials as well as full documentation.

- [Developer Center Getting Started tutorials](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started)
- [Knowledge Center](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSNJXP/welcome.html)

You also do not mention which platform you are targeting. The answer will vary depending on the platform.

**Changing splash image, application icons**
In general, these images will reside un the your-app\environment-folder\native folder. Look there and you will find the images.

You can read more here: [Application resources](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_6.3.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/r_application_resources.html)

**Displaying a busy indicator**
You can opt to use any indicator plug-n you find online, or use the one provided by Worklight.

To use Worklight's busyIndicator you need to:

1. Initialize it in common\js\main.js:

var busy;

```
function wlCommonInit() {
    busy = new WL.BusyIndicator( null, {text : 'Loading...'});
}
```

2. To display it, whenever you need it - for example before invoking an adapter request you would do:

   busy.show();
3. To remove, for example after receiving an adapter response you would do:

   busy.hide();

You can read more here: [Common UI controls](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-6-3/advanced-client-side-development/common-ui-controls/#busyindicator)

---

Again, go and read and follow the Developer Center tutorials in order to learn how to use the product and implementing applications using it.

Comment: default Image in Android environment 202X322 picel and Name is:splash.9.png.. according to document what i understand is file name and piccel should match.. if device size change is their any effect with the splash screen

Comment: No. You need to read about 9Patch: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html

Comment: idan iam not able to modify image using 9patch tool

Comment: I can't help you with that; you need to learn to use the tool.

Comment: thx Idan I worked on Busy Indicator.. its working.. thx. its der any plugin for BusyIndicator which look same on all environment.. i worked on default..

Comment: The busy indicator provided by worklight will give you the native look & feel for each platform. If you want the same look & feel, you need to use a 3rd party plug-in to achieve it.

Comment: k thax Idan.. BusyIndicator Worked For Me.. now Iam Looking for Splashscreen and App Icon